# Content Security Policy frame-ancestors. Iframe wont load content in iOS10

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe, ios10, content-security-policy

Our Cordova app won't load iframe contents on iOS 10.

We have some iframes displaying certain information's from our web pages inside the app, so we don't have to duplicate them.

Which works fine in any of the below iOS versions. But since the update on our devices, the app refuses to load the resources.

```
Refused to load http://.../.../X.html because it does not appear in the frame-ancestors directive of the Content Security Policy
```

I have tried to edit my meta Content-Security-Policy tag to allow from this resource, but that didn't work. I guess this issue is about the web server telling my app/browser to not allow this origin, but I'm sadly not that deep in that topic. What I know is that the web server sets the X-Frame-Options to SAMEORIGIN, but that should disable it for the other iOS versions as well..

So how can I bypass the security configurations in this case, so it works just like in the earlier version of iOS?

Please tell me if you need more information's, I can't tell if I missed something.

Answer (score 5):

> What I know is that the web server sets the X-Frame-Options to SAMEORIGIN, but that should disable it for the other iOS versions as well.

In addition to the existing header:

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Add its Content Security Policy equivalent:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
```

Keep the following caveats in mind:

> A word about support. Not supported in all browsers yet, Chrome 40+ and FF 35+ support, but will also default to X-Frame-Options if it exists. Spec says, CSP should take precedence. This will not work when CSP is in a `<meta>` tag, and will not work when using Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only.

**References**

- [Content Security Policy Cheat Sheet - OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: I cannot really verify that answer. Project is long gone. How to we do this?